# Draw an image on JPanel multiple times with mouse clicks

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to draw images on JPanel when a specific button is clicked. When a button with a circle is pressed, then I should be able to draw a circle image, and similarly with a rectangle button. I can draw but only once which means that the previously drawn image is erased.

```
public class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    Image image;
    Image image2;
    private Point drawPoint;

    public Panel1(){
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        image = toolkit.getImage("JavaIcon\\p3.png");
        image2 = toolkit.getImage("JavaIcon\\t.png");

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                drawPoint = new Point(e.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }

        });

    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        if (drawPoint != null) {
            if(i==1){
                g2d.drawImage(image, drawPoint.x, drawPoint.y, this);
            }
            if(i==2){
                g2d.drawImage(image2, drawPoint.x, drawPoint.y, this);
            }
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

In the 'if statements' I indicate whether a certain button is clicked, if 1, then a circle button is clicked.

[image: Example of drawing a circle]

**LATEST EDIT**

It still erases the previously drawn circle:

```
ArrayList<drawnCircle> list1 = new ArrayList<drawnCircle>();

public void addCircle(Image image, Point point){

        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
        image = toolkit.getImage("JavaIcon\\p3.png");

        drawnCircle dc = new drawnCircle(image, point);
        list1.add(dc);
        repaint();
    }
    public void clear(){
        list1.clear();
        repaint();
    }

    class drawnCircle{
        private Image image;
        private Point point;

        public drawnCircle(Image image, Point myPoint){
            this.image = image;
            this.point = myPoint;
        }
        public Image getImage(){
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(Image image){
            this.image = image;
        }
        public Point getPoint(){
            return point;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question/problem? What is wrong with your posted code? How is it not working?

Comment: I draw a circle as it is seen, then I draw again on another location, and the first circle is erased. It appears now that I can draw only once. I want to keep all the images without any of them being erased.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, `What is wrong with your posted code? How is it not working?` it was already stated in the question. `I can draw but only once which means that the previously drawn image is erased.`

Comment: @camickr I tried to use your code from the previously asked question but it gives me the error that list cannot be resolved. I am trying to store images in it, as I am using them.

Comment: I add the image to a list with a new function as seen in the edit, but still erases the previously drawn image.

Comment: @Danny `it gives me the error that list cannot be resolved` That is a basic Java problem. You need to import the proper package that contains the "List" interface and the ArrayList class. Read the Java API to find the proper package needed for both of those classes.

Comment: You can't just add the Image to the List you also need to store the location of where the image needs to be painted. Look at the working example code. I store a custom Object in the List. It contains the Rectangle (which includes information about size/location of the rectangle) and it stores the Color. So you also need two pieces of information. The image and the Point where it should be painted.

Comment: Good luck, I'm off golfing now...

Comment: @camickr I edited again the code, but it is still not working. It erases the image and then I draw again. It doesn't keep them in a list. Just to mention I've been using Java since last week and I am not very familiar.

Comment: @camickr: yes, I saw that after posting the comment, which is why I closed it with your answer that essentially addressed the same issues.

Comment: @Danny, Did you download the working example and test it? So start with the working code an make changes.